# Angular js - Format String in Modal with correct spaces

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a popup which has the following output! The output is just one complete string with spaces and newline characters. But each line is concatenated to the previous line. So, each line can be adjusted individually.

```
Test1                        :  Success :    200
Test2              :  Success :    200
Test3                  :  Success :    200
Test4                :  Success :    200
Test5                  :  Success  :    404
Test6           :  Success  :    401
```

Since I have multiple such popups and multiple tests for each popup. Is there a way I can format the strings to have a proper indents? That is I would like my output to be :

```
Test1               :  Success :    200
Test2               :  Success :    200
Test3               :  Success :    200
Test4               :  Success :    200
Test5               :  Success :    404
Test6               :  Success :    401
```

Comment: The only way I can see is to pinpoint the 3 columns using regex (or whatever your poison is) by targeting the `:` character. Then building up a new result set with a fixed max length for each new column.

Comment: Can you post the code where you bind/assign the results to whatever output element/property you're using?

Comment: @RohanBüchner - To post the code, I was making the changes, but the answer suggested by Tanmay solved it. :) Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

First, split your string with `\n` to get each line in array. Next, split again with `:` and `trim` to remove variable spaces.

Finally, join them again but with first element appended with extra space which would be same for each one of them.

```js
let str = "Test1                        :  Success :    200\nTest2              :  Success :    200\nTest3                  :  Success :    200\nTest4                :  Success :    200\nTest5                  :  Success  :    404\nTest6           :  Success  :    401"


let arr = str.split("\n")

let res = arr.map(function(st) {
  let temp = st.split(":")
  return temp.map(s => s.trim())
})

let final = res.map(function(a) {
  a[0] = a[0] + "            "
  return a.join(" : ")
})

console.log(final)
```

Comment: damn you're quick :P